# Show full application name on Home screen

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher, application-name

My app name contains 12 characters. But application launcher icon appears with truncated text.
As i observed this issue is not produced in all device. I am using device with OS 4.0.3.

App launcher icon should show full app name regardless of app name length.

Is there any property available in Android Manifest to set app name without eclipsing? or Is it default behavior of device that apply on all launcher icons?

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine a name like `TheCoolestAppIveEverDoneAndWantToBeDisplayedCompletely`. Imagine that to be forcing its whole title to show.

This is why there is no such option. And there really is none. The only thing you could do is develop your own launcher or contact the devs of other third-party launchers.

Comment: How to overcome this problem?

Comment: most of the devices, have a marquee on the text such that the whole text is visible. There is nothing you could perhaps do

Comment: App name will be appear as per the device configuration. We can't do anything. right?

Comment: Exactly. There is no way. At least none that will work for any launcher on any device.

Comment: Can i separately  set app launcher name? Means app launcher name is diff and app name is diff.

Comment: Say My app name is "HelloAndroidTest". Its not enough to fit in app launcher icon text. I want that app launcher icon should show just "Hello" without changing app name.

Comment: You could change the activity's label of course: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label

Comment: It showing short name in recent app. Full name should print in recent app thumb.

Comment: Yes, because the label is used there as well.

Comment: can u give me your gmail id so we can chat over there.

What is the solution?

Comment: 1. No, 2. There is no solution other than would you have already.

Comment: I set short name to launcher activity. But to show full name in action bar of activity i called setTitle() in onCreate() of activity. But issue is for a fraction of second short name displayed before replacing with full name.